# surviving symbols in GC-section

Tags: llvm, lld

i am writing proposal for GSOC, in project i have to preserve surviving symbol during "-print-gc-sections", so need to know what is surviving symbols?

Comment: Have you tried to ask the mentor for this project? There is a dedicated LLVM Discourse thread for this: https://discourse.llvm.org/t/lld-linker-improvements-for-embedded/68129

Comment: Hii @AntonKorobeynikov, i had asked but anyone was not responding.